# HTML Superscript & Subscript Issue

Tags: html, css, subscript, superscript

Adding superscript and subscript for a given text doesn't work as expected. However it works exactly as expected before the text.

Chemical elements use superscripts and subscripts before and after an atomic symbol to specify mass number, atomic number, charge, and atom count. An accurate depiction is given in the attached image. The code I'm using is given below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style>
    .right-align {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: -0.3em;
   vertical-align: -0.4em;
   line-height: 1.0em;
   font-size: 80%;
   text-align: right;
    }

    .left-align {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: -0.3em;
   vertical-align: 0.8em;
   line-height: 1.0em;
   font-size: 80%;
   text-align: left;
    }

    .super-sub {
   font-size: inherit;
   line-height: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
    }
 </style>


 <body>
  <span style="white-space: wrap !important;">
   <span class="right-align">
    <sup class="super-sub">238</sup>
    <br/>
    <sub class="super-sub">92</sub>
   </span>U<span class="left-align">
    <sup class="super-sub">3-</sup>
    <br/>
    <sub class="super-sub">1</sub>
   </span>
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

There's no error message. The first image shows how the result must be formatted. The second image how the image is actually formatted (number 1 pushes the 3-).

[image: Expected result must follow the format given in this image]

[image: In the actual image the atom count 1 pushes the charge 3- up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want simplify things using `flex`:

```css
body {
  font-size: 48px
}

.element {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.3
}

.element > * {
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: .75em;
  line-height: 1;
}

.element>*:nth-child(3),
.element>*:nth-child(4) {
  align-self: flex-start
}
```

```html
<span class="element">
  <sup>238</sup>
  <sub>92</sub>
  U
  <sup>3-</sup>
  <sub>1</sub>
</span>
```

Comment: This is concise and I like it. I have to figure out to right align 238 & 92 and left align 3- & 1. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VelusamyVelu, thank you, I've updated my answer to reflect your alignment requirements.

Comment: That's the perfect solution I have seen so far. Thank you very much for your help. --V. Velu

Comment: Can you give me some idea about metrics in the style and how they are related please? I attempted to figure out on my own but I'm not sure I'm getting it right.

Comment: @VelusamyVelu, sure, what's your question?

Comment: Kosh Very - Why is the font size is set to .5em for .element>*?
What's the safe way to increase the super/subscript to 75% of the main character (U in this case) which number is to be changed?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: @VelusamyVelu, `1em` is the size of `U`, so `0.5em` is `50%` of its size. If you need 75%, set `.75em`.

Comment: @VelusamyVelu, I've updated my answer to have super/subscript set to 75% of U.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the letter U inside another span and then adjust the vertical-align of the left align. I have increased the font-size for better readability and also changed the left and right align classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html>
<style>
  .left-align {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -0.3em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .right-align {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -0.3em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .center-align {
    font-size: 150%;
    margin: 0.2em;
  }
  
  .super-sub {
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
</style>

</html>

<body>
  <span style="white-space: wrap !important;">
            <span class="left-align">
                <sup class="super-sub">238</sup><br/>
                <sub class="super-sub">92</sub>
            </span><span class="center-align">U</span><span class="right-align">
                <sup class="super-sub">3-</sup><br/>
                <sub class="super-sub">1</sub>
            </span>
  </span>

</html>
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you Manoj.